# Separate LatLng into String Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I got my latlng from my draggable marker.. How can I separate the getLatLng value into lat and longitude? Remember, not String to LatLng. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To clarify you've got a `LatLng` value and you want the separate values for each?

```
var myLatLng = myMarker.getPosition();
var lat = myLatLng.lat();
var lng = myLatLng.lng();
```

You should look at the docs for [`LatLng` in the reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng)

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you can try to use geocoder to separate your latlng

```
geocoder.getLatLng(yourlatlng, function(point){
    if(!point){
        alert(address + " not found");
    }else{
        lat = point.y;
        longi = point.x;
    }                                                   
});
```

Comment: But why go through all this trouble when the `LatLng` object specifically supports grabbing the values separately from each other with a simple `lat()` or `lng()` call?  This is a ton of extra code to wrap something natively supported by the initial object.